# importing random words from a file without duplicates Python

Tags: python, list, random, set, text-files

I'm attempting to create a program which selects 10 words from a text file which contains 10+ words. For the purpose of the program when importing these 10 words from the text file, I must not import the same words twice! Currently I'm utilising a list for this however the same words seem to appear. I have some knowledge of sets and know they cannot hold the same value twice. As of now I'm clueless on how to solve this any help would be much appreciated. THANKS!

please find relevant code below! -(p.s. `FileSelection` is basically open file dialog)

```
def GameStage03_E():
    global WordList
    if WrdCount >= 10:
        WordList = []
        for n in range(0,10):
            FileLines = open(FileSelection).read().splitlines()
            RandWrd = random.choice(FileLines)
            WordList.append(RandWrd)
        SelectButton.destroy()
        GameStage01Button.destroy()
        GameStage04_E()
    elif WrdCount <= 10:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", " Insufficient Amount Of Words Within Your Text File! ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `WordList` a `set`:

```
WordList = set()
```

Then `update` that set instead of appending:

```
WordList.update(set([RandWrd]))
```

Of course `WordList` would be a bad name for a set.

There are a few other problems though:

- Don't use uppercase names for variables and functions (follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- What happens if you draw the same word twice in your loop? There is no guarantee that `WordList` will contain 10 items after the loop completes, if words may appear multiple times.

The latter might be addressed by changing your loop to:

```
    while len(WordList) < 10:
        FileLines = open(FileSelection).read().splitlines()
        RandWrd = random.choice(FileLines)
        WordList.update(set([RandWrd]))
```

You would have to account for the case that there don't exist 10 distinct words after all, though.

Even then the loop would still be quite inefficient as you might draw the same word over and over and over again with `random.choice(FileLines)`. But maybe you can base something useful off of that.

Comment: yeah I knew that would be a problem... just thought there would maybe be a way around it....  is there a way to limit the amount of words that are in a set?

Comment: Why not check the length of the set in each iteration and break when the limit is exceeded?

Comment: for the love of everything could you tell me how? I think that response has made me fall in love XD I cant thank you enough man!

Answer (score -1):

not sure i understand you right, but ehehe,
line 3: "if wrdcount"  . .  where dit you give wrdcount a value ?
Maybe you intent something along the line below?:

```
wordset = {}
wrdcount = len(wordset)
while wrdcount < 10:
    # do some work to update the setcode here
    # when end-of-file break
```

Comment: wrdcount is a previous variable g

Comment: hmm, but your function does not have "global wrdcount"  so inside the function the wrdcount has no value to begin with. Further when you need 10 values, maybe use "while" until you get 10 values ?

Comment: wrdcount is not the issue here